# mysql insert PHP statement keeps throwing error

Tags: php

Does anybody know why the following `PHP` code keeps throwing errors: I have been unable to log any proper error other than the if statement $result not going through and giving me the `Echo 'Error'` statement. Is there something wrong with my insertion?

```
    $new_tbl_name = 'Password_Reset';

   $sql = "INSERT INTO $new_tbl_name (Email, Key) VALUES ('$email','$resetHash')";

   $result = mysql_query($sql);


    if ($result) {
    }
    else {
       echo 'Error';
     }
```

Comment: Echo mysql_error() to get more specific information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), you'll have to escape it:

```
INSERT INTO $new_tbl_name (Email, `Key`) VALUES
                                  ^   ^
```

As a general suggestion, simply saying "error" is utterly useless for debugging purposes. Have mysql TELL you what's wrong:

```
if (!$result) {
   die(mysql_error());
}
```

so you have a clue as to what's wrong, instead of just poking around in the dark.

Comment: wow. Unbelievable. Thank you for saving me from breaking some

Comment: The error message probably wouldn't have helped in this case anyway. MySQL's syntax errors tend to be very generic. All it probably would say is that the error is at the word `Key`, but it won't tell you WHY it's wrong.